# which widget can be used to explain functionality in app

Tags: flutter, widget, label, tooltip

I want to explain something in my app and add a widget which looks like a notification or chat. I want this widget to be visible for some time and then get dismissed. I tried using `tooltip` but it is visible only when I click it.
Which widget can I use?

Comment: perhaps https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/highlighter_coachmark

Comment: Yeah I could use that as an alternative but mine is a utility app and it might become annoying to see such hints all the time. That's why I was looking for something like notification popups.

Comment: You use a Stack (wrap your whole app) or Overlay.

Answer (score 0):

The Dart package [intro_views_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intro_views_flutter) is what you need, but one of its main limitations is that it is displayed on full screen, if that is not an issue to you, then you should take a look at it. Or you can use a `showDialog` method inside a `Future` function this way :

```
 Future showNotification() async {
  showDialog<String>(
     context: context,
     child: new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Note!') ,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          content: //any widget you want to display here                         
      ),
    );
  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
     Navigator.of(context).pop(); // this will dismiss the dialog automatically after five seconds
  }
}
```

then when you need it call:

```
 showNotificaion();
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing this package but I don't want the explanation to be at the start of app. Once user is at a particular screen, I want pop up to come and explain why there is a button and what will it do.

Comment: hope this alternative solution helps

Comment: Won't this be always at the middle of screen? I will not be able to point the dialog to my button and also when pop up comes, the screen becomes kind of faded right? When I am explaining the widget I would want it to be on same screen right.. Really appreciate your effort though:)

Comment: Well, I guessed that would help, but no problem. Sometimes you have to find some creative work-around, post your solution here when you find it.

Comment: Will do. Thanks :)